# Convert Exposure Time in seconds to a fraction

Tags: exposure, metadata

I'm writing my own software to manage my photo storage.

Within the EXIF data the camera stores it's exposure time in seconds.

So 1/60 is expressed as 0.0166666666666667.

Sites like Flickr are already able to convert this into the more friendler "1/60" format, but what is the formula to achieve this?

I.e, how to find out how many times the value will fit into 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1/0.0166666666666667 = 60
quite easy :)

Comment: Cheers I got there in the end - I was confused because the calculator was giving me 59.99999999999988.

Comment: well, some rounding is in order, obviously. with floats, thats always a problem.